# Table of Contents Capitals for both "CHAPTER 1" as well as its name "PRACTICAL PHILOSOPHY."

Tags: table-of-contents

I cannot find anyplace to clarify this or send me in the correct direction. At the beginning of Chapters and in the TOC, it begins "Chapter 1." and needs to be "CHAPTER 1", with a double space after. My title then follows in all caps and this is happening automatically. I cannot find where the TOC command is getting "Chapter 1." in the TOC or for the Chapters themselves.

Not that advanced in knowing how to change style files, which I got from my university. But it was for EE and I am humanities trying to make it work for Turabian Style, Chicago style.

Here's the relevant portion of the `utdallas.sty` file. It has entries for everything but the chapters themselves, but adding the Appendix and such is there since they need the `addcontentsline`.

```
\def\appendixname{APPENDIX}

\def\appendix{\clearpage
    \typeout{APPENDIX.}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centerline{\normalsize APPENDIX}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \nopage@addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}
    \chap@or@app=2
    \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}

\def\appendices{\clearpage
    \typeout{APPENDICES.}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \centerline{\normalsize APPENDICES}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \nopage@addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}
    \chap@or@app=2
    \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.\hspace*{1em}\uppercase{#1}}\else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\uppercase{CHAPTER}}\fi
    \chaptermark{#1}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}
    \@makechapterhead{#2} \@afterheading
    \ifnum\chap@or@app=1\ifnum\value{chapter}=1     % if Chapter 1
        \markboth{}{}\pagestyle{myheadings}
        \pagenumbering{arabic}\fi\fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}}

\def\@schapter#1{\thispagestyle{plain}
    \@makeschapterhead{#1} \@afterheading}

%%% Stolen from latex.tex (to unindent the first para of (sub)sections)
\def\@startsection#1#2#3#4#5#6{\if@noskipsec \leavevmode \fi
   \par \@tempskipa #4\relax
   \@afterindentfalse
   \if@nobreak \everypar{}
   \else\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}\addvspace{\@tempskipa}\fi
   \@ifstar{\@ssect{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
           {\@dblarg{\@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}}}

\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {4.6ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{.3ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\it}} % Moh
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {3.9ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{.2ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\it}} % Moh
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}{.1ex plus .2ex}{\normalsize\it}}

\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{REFERENCES}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
```

Comment: from your description of what's happening, it looks like the "Chapter" string is specified by `\@chapapp`, so adding this to your preamble should make it uppercase: `\makeatletter\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{CHAPTER}\makeatother`. some of the code for `\@chapter` looks rather odd though.

Comment: @barbarabeeton -- In the `book` and `report` classes, one finds `\newcommand\@chapapp{\chaptername}` and also `\newcommand\chaptername{Chapter}`. Hence, redefining either `\chaptername` or `\@chapapp` to `CHAPTER` should serve the OP's purposes.

Comment: @Mico -- thanks.  you dug deeper than i did.

Comment: @Mico -- only redefining `\@chapapp`, but not `\chaptername` worked for me, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

I would try inserting the command

```
\renewcommand\chaptername{CHAPTER}
```

in the document's preamble.